# react render - objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to loop through my events in my render:

```
let {events} = this.props;

    if(events.length > 0) {
       const events = events.map((event) => <Text>{event.author}</Text>);
    }

    if (this.props.hasErrored) {
        return <Text>Sorry! There was an error loading the events</Text>;
    }

    if (this.props.isLoading) {
        return <Text>Loading…</Text>;
    }

    return (
        <View>
          {events}
        </View>
    );
```

The error in full is:

**Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {events, rest_url, total, total_pages})**

Any ideas?

Comment: the `events` variable that is actually rendered is the first one and not second one. let and const are scope dependent so your const event is not available outside of the if

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const`s and `let`s are [block scoped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block), so the issue belongs to your `events` variable. You can remove the `if` statement which belong to `events` variable & move it to `render` method, like below:

```
const {events} = this.props;

if (this.props.hasErrored) {
  return <Text>Sorry! There was an error loading the events</Text>;
}

if (this.props.isLoading) {
  return <Text>Loading…</Text>;
}

return (
  <View>
    {events && events.length && events.map((event) => <Text>{event.author}</Text>)}
  </View>
);
```

Comment: A linter like [eslint](https://eslint.org/) will help you catch these. See the [`no-shadow`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow#rule-details) rule.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is:

```
return (
    <View>
      {events}
    </View>
);
```

I guess `events` is a regular JavaScript object? In this case React doesn't know how to render it.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new events variable in first if condition.

Just delete the `const` inside first if statement